# Locks on Office documents since beginning of july 2023 (using Webdav)

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, webdav, office-2016

A customer experiences major problems using SharePoint via webdav since the beginning of july. A document can be saved in SharePoint (2019 on premise) but cannot re saved again, a lock persists for one hour. Some people on the web talk about a bad Office 365 update, but my customer uses Office 2016 and 2019 versions.

Has anybody any clue about it? What can be done about that?